# Поиск корня уравнения f(x)=0 на отрезке методом Ньютона(секущих)

Tags: c++, методы

Имеется уравнение 1-x+sin(x)-ln(1+x)=0 нашел ее производную cos(x)-1-1/(x+1), вообщем программа работает корректно, но не уверен, что она правильно рассчитывает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double function(double x)
{
    return 1-x+sin(x)-log(1+x);
}
double derivative(double x)
{
    return cos(x) - 1 - 1/(x+1);
}

int main()
{
    double a, b; //Границы интервала
    double eps; //Точность
    double x0; //Начальная точка 
    double xn,x; //Первое приближение
    double root; //Корень

    cout << "Введите границы a и b " <<endl;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "Введите начальную точку x0 " << endl;
    cin >> x0;

    cout << "Введите погрешность EPS " << endl;
    cin >> eps;

    do
    {
        xn = -function(x0) / derivative(x0);
        x = x0 + xn;
        x0 = x;
    }
    while (fabs(x0-x) > eps);
        root = x;
    cout << "Искомый корень " << root << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну подставляйте полученное значение в уравнение и смотрите, что получится - в чем проблема?...

Comment: Однозначно неправильно. Сначала у вас присваивается `x0=x`, а потом вычисляется разность между ними. Таким образом, цикл у вас всегда выполнится только один раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Не проверял, но должно работать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double function(double x)
{
    return 1-x+sin(x)-log(1+x);
}
double derivative(double x)
{
    return cos(x) - 1 - 1/(x+1);
}

int main()
{
    double a, b; //Границы интервала
    double eps; //Точность
    double x0; //Начальная точка 
    double xn,x; //Первое приближение
    double root; //Корень

    cout << "Введите границы a и b " <<endl;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "Введите начальную точку x0 " << endl;
    cin >> x0;

    cout << "Введите погрешность EPS " << endl;
    cin >> eps;
    x = x0
    while (true)
    {
        xn = x - function(x) / derivative(x);
        if (fabs(x - xn) < eps)
            break;
        x = xn;
    }

    root = xn;
    cout << "Искомый корень " << root << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

UPD. Вариант с контролем сходимости

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double function(double x)
{
    return 1-x+sin(x)-log(1+x);
}
double derivative(double x)
{
    return cos(x) - 1 - 1/(x+1);
}
bool newton(double a, double b, double eps, double x0, double &root)
{
    double x, xn;
    x = x0;
    while (true)
    {
        xn = x - function(x) / derivative(x);
        if (fabs(x - xn) < eps)
            break;
        x = xn;
        if ((x < a) || (x > b))
            return false;
    }
    root = xn;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    double a, b; //Границы интервала
    double eps; //Точность
    double x0; //Начальная точка 
    double root; //Корень

    cout << "Введите границы a и b " <<endl;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "Введите начальную точку x0 " << endl;
    cin >> x0;

    cout << "Введите погрешность EPS " << endl;
    cin >> eps;
    if (newton(a, b, eps, x0, root))
    {
        cout << "Искомый корень " << root << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Решение не найдено" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: программа выводит один и тот же корень в независимости какие границы были введены, так же вообщем как и у меня...

Comment: @Bombucho, Не вижу в этом проблемы, ведь указанное вами уравнение имеет [один корень](http://umath.ru/calc/graph/?&func=1-x+sin(x)-ln(x+1);).

Comment: тогда независимо от указанных границ интервалов корень никак изменится не может и по сути будет верен только для границ которые привязаны(в задании) к этой функции , и дело в том, что в моей работе корень = 1.4818, а при учете вашей поправки корень не кардинально изменился и = 1.4744 или как раз в этой самой разнице и заключается ошибка?

Comment: @Bombucho, На каждом шаге значение `xn` приближается к действительному корню. У вас выполнялся только один шаг, у меня их выполняется столько, чтобы обеспечить точность, заданную параметром `eps`. Чему он у вас равен? Хотя, судя по графику, истиный корень равен 1,1520.

Comment: Только что проверил: при точности 0,0001 корень получается 1,14744.

Comment: А по поводу границ - вы же нигде их не проверяете. Границы задают для контроля сходимости алгоритма. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: спасибо, да с корнем я 1-цу упустил...

Comment: Ещё рекомендую вам самостоятельно проверить условие `a<x0<b`. Если оно не выполняется, решений нет.

Comment: я может не так понял, но x0 пользователь вводит самостоятельно

Comment: Верно. Именно поэтому введённое значение нужно проверить на правильность.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы должно работать:

```
double newton_method(double x0, double eps = 0.0001){
  double x = x0;
  double dx;
  do
  {
      dx = - function(x) / derivative(x);
      x += dx;
  }
  while (fabs(dx) >= eps); 
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Вот только при смене границ, корень выводится тот же...

Comment: @Bombucho, а почему это не должно быть так? Метод Ньютона ищет один корень, если у вас их несколько, он может найти любой из них, в зависимости от начальной точки. Границы для метода Ньтона нужны только для того, чтобы узнать, что он расходится (а условия сходимости у него строгие, на практике обычно страхуются, беря две разные начальные точки, и проверяют результаты на совпадение)